# Unable to select options in materializecss select

Tags: css, materialize

I am having issue in select element of materializecss.

In my jade file

```
//Stylesheets
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/css/materialize.min.css' )

//Vendor Scripts
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js')
        script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/js/materialize.min.js')
```

In my controller I am initializing the component as

```
$('select').material_select();
```

In my HTML I am using as

```
<label>Materialize Select</label>
<select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

However when I try to select the options nothing happens.

below is what displayed after initialization

[image]

HTMl that gets generated looks like below

```
<div class="col s4 input-field">
   <div class="select-wrapper">
      <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-b9fd5517-0d0d-40ff-ab29-d37fc9a8d05f" value="Choose your option">
      <select class="initialized">
         <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>
         <option value="1">Option 1</option>
         <option value="2">Option 2</option>
         <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see ul element is not getting generated which gets generated after initialization.

Any clue what could be issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your javascript look like this..

```
$(function() {
   $('select').material_select();
});
```

..and your HTML like this?

```
<html>
    <head>
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with 0.97.2 version

see below

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2265